# Apex5, tick all and untick all checkbox

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want a checkbox in an Interactive Report (IR), and I want the users to be able to quickly Select All or Unselect All of them  with a single checkbox in the header.
Added java scripted code but it's not working any idea .....

```
if ( $( '#selectunselectall' ).is(':checked') ) {
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',true);
Else 
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',false);
```

Comment: https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/11/15/select-all-unselect-all-checkbox-in-interactive-report-header/

Comment: Hi I've tried it but it's not working as it should... I.e first tick all and untick all it's ok but if after the uncheck I tick again it's not doing tick all again ... Any idea wht need to be included in the step ?

Comment: not sure - open the Developer Console and check if there are any javascript errors being reported.

Comment: Getting dynamic action fired native JavaScript code debug.is:247 ...  any specific object to check in the log??

Comment: Check the console log after enabling the Apex Debug mode.

Comment: How to enable that ? I'm absolutely new in that

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e11838/debug.htm#HTMDB10000

Answer (score 4):

1. Add the checkbox to the query, e.g. `apex_item.checkbox(1, record_id) as selected`.
2. Set the region Static ID to some value, e.g. `myreport`
3. Set the following attributes of column “SELECTED”:

   Heading = `<input type="checkbox" id="selectunselectall">`

   Escape Special Characters = No

   Enable Users To = (uncheck all options, including Hide, Sort, etc.)
4. Add a Dynamic Action:

   Event = Change

   Selection Type = jQuery Selector

   jQuery Selector = #selectunselectall

   Event Scope = Dynamic

   Static Container (jQuery Selector) = #myreport

   True Action = Execute JavaScript Code

   Fire On Page Load = No

   Code =

   ```
   if ($( '#myreport #selectunselectall' ).is(':checked')) {
     $('#myreport input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',true);
   } else {
     $('#myreport input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').attr('checked',false);
   }
   ```

Amendment made to jeff's code:

```
    if ($( '#myreport #selectunselectall' ).is(':checked')) {
      $('#myreport input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').prop('checked',true);
    } else {
      $('#myreport input[type=checkbox][name=f01]').prop('checked',false);
    }
```

[jQuery API - .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

[Jeff Kemp's select/unselect all](https://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/11/15/select-all-unselect-all-checkbox-in-interactive-report-header/)

Have a look at the above link. Jeff Kemp has done a great job documenting your objective.

Comment: I've actually written two articles about this: one for a checkbox in a report, and one for a single checkbox item with multiple values. This link is for the latter.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp dang it.. I totally meant to provide that second link instead of what I actually provided. Thanks for stepping in and for teaching me many neat tricks!

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp, ... i have a wkrspace online can u pls make a demo?? netapps /netspirit01@gmail.com.. pwd: password01

Comment: @net I'd be happy to take a look at your work. It'd be better if you recreated your issue in this workspace.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any of these steps yet. If you wanted me to do the work for you I can, but I do charge by the hour for private consulting work.

Comment: I've done the mentioned steps.. on my dev envir its not working on second tick-all.. No prbs can replicate it online... u can check it in my online workspace...apps 72603, page2 checkbox

Comment: the checkbox column in your report had a type of "percent graph" when it should have had a type of "Plain Text". After changing the type to "Plain Text" i also set the "Escape special characters" property to "No".

Comment: however, the issue is still present. I'm noticing though while it appears that the checkbox is unselected.. the checked property is actually working properly. This issue is only cosmetic. I'll spend some more time looking at this tomorrow.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp the issue has been corrected. .attr('checked' was changed to .prop('checked' Jeff can you confirm that this was the right solution? I feel this may be worthy of an update to your site.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help

Comment: @net you're welcome. If we've resolved your issue please mark the answer as accepted. Special thanks to Jeff for the heavy lifting.